# What can be moved safely to local ssd on Ubuntu Azure VM?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, azure, ssd, apache2

I have an **Azure VM** which recently have been resized to D2 size form A2 Basic so it **has a new SSD local disk** (a temporal disk with no persistence guarantee).

Now it has the swap file, but I think it can be used for more temporary things. **What can be moved safely to this disk?** For example is safe to move the `/tmp` folder?

It is an Ubuntu server, used as a web server (Apache, MySQL).

Comment: I don't know who downvote you. what do you mean moved safely to this disk? move files to this disk?

Comment: I mean what files/folders can be configured to be there instead of the OS disk without the risk of losing it. Like if it's a good idea to put/mount the `/tmp` folder in local disk or some parts of ubuntu could crash in an event which clears the disk? Or changing cache-like folders from MySQL, Apache to be there can be a problem?

Comment: About the downvote, whoever was, please comment why or I can't improve the question and myself.

Answer (score 2):

> For example is safe to move the /tmp folder?

As we know, the data store in temporary disk will be lose when this VM restart or some update to this host.

The temporary disk is SSD, have a good performance, we can use it like this:

If your workflow involves getting content from the blob, processing it and storing it back to the blob then you could download content to the temporary storage, process the content, then take the processed content and save it back to the blob.

Here a official documentation about how to use temporary disk with SQL server, please refer to this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sql/virtual-machines-windows-sql-performance).

> Temporary disk: Azure Virtual Machines contain another disk called the
>   temporary disk (labeled as the D: drive). This is a disk on the node
>   that can be used for scratch space.
>
> Temporary disk
>
> The temporary storage drive, labeled as the D: drive, is not persisted
>   to Azure blob storage. Do not store your user database files or user
>   transaction log files on the D: drive. For D-series, Dv2-series, and
>   G-series VMs, the temporary drive on these VMs is SSD-based. If your
>   workload makes heavy use of TempDB (e.g. for temporary objects or
>   complex joins), storing TempDB on the D drive could result in higher
>   TempDB throughput and lower TempDB latency.